Are 'get something ready' and 'get something going' examples of causative constructions?
When I search for information about causative verbs, the verb 'get' specifically, two major structures come up:

Get somebody to do something - convince/cause somebody to do something
Get something done (Passive Causative)

My question is, what about constructions like 'get + object + adjective (get something ready)' and 'get + object + Verb-ing (get something going)?' Is it fair to say that those are other uses of 'get' as a causative verb? Because 'get' in these phrases has a meaning of 'to cause'. And is there a grammatical name for these constructions?
UPDATE: Thank you for answers and comments. I'd like to give some examples to clarify.
She needs to get ready - not causative.
She needs to get her kids ready - is that causative?
He needs to get going. - not causative.
He needs to get his group going. - causative?

"He got the room ready" isn't a causative, it's just "get" with an object complement.

@StuartF Yes it is. It means "He made the room ready", i.e. he caused the room to become ready.

This is all you need: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/causatives-have-get.html That said, this question belongs on ELL, not here.

The constructions here considered are reckoned with in A Comprehensive grammar of the English Language (Quirk et al, 1985), as multi-word verb constructions, all being idiomatic verb phrases. the most important subclass of verbs in the class of multi-word verb constructions are the so-called phrasal verbs, "phrasal verb" being nowadays considered to be an unsatisfactory term. The subclass in which is found "get ready" and "get < something > going", instead of consisting of combinations of adverbial particles and prepositions with a simple verb form, are made up of a simple verb form and an adjective (VERB-ADJECTIVE COMBINATION), or a simple verb form and another verb form (VERB-VERB COMBINATION), or, finally, of verbs governing two prepositions.

(CoGEL § 16.17) Other multi-word verb constructions
Apart from the types of multi-word verb [resulting from combinations with adverbial particles and prepositions], some
other idiomatic verb constructions may be briefly noted.
(a) VERB-ADJECTIVE COMBINATIONS
These are similar to phrasal verbs. Compare:

Meg put the cloth straight.
Meg put the cat out.

Like phrasal verbs, verb-adjective combinations form cohesive units; but unlike phrasal verbs1, some of them allow comparative modification:

John didn't put the cloth as straight as Meg. (correct)
John didn't put the cat as out as Meg.  (unacceptable)

They may be either copular (clause pattern SVC), or complex transitive (clause pattern SVOC):
SVC: break even, plead guilty, lie low
SVOC: cut < Noun > short, work < Noun > loose, rub < Noun > dry
Sometimes the idiom contains additional elements, such as an infinitive (play hard to get) or a preposition (ride roughshod over. . .).
(The '< Noun >' above indicates a direct object in the case of transitive examples.

In the case of "get something ready" there is no possible comparison.

Joan didn't get the diner as ready as Jane.  (unacceptable)

The clause pattern is "SVOC" (obviously).

(CoGEL § 16.17)
(b) VERB-VERB COMBINATIONS
In these idiomatic constructions […], the second verb is nonfinite, and may be either an infinitive:
make do with, make (< Noun >) do, let (< Noun >) go, let (< Noun >) be
or a participle, with or without a following preposition:
put paid to, get rid of, have done with
leave < Noun > standing, send < Noun > packing, knock < Noun > flying, get going

"Get < Noun > going" does not figure in the list above, but  this is merely an omission because the list of those verbs is very long.
reference (McGraw-Hill’s Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial
Expressions.
(when "< something >" is literally "something")
Farlex
HINATIVE (US)
WordReference
This is not a causative verbal construction because no one is made to do the action for somebody else, as can be made clear through the meaning. (causative: have and get)
1 In CoGEL, phrasal verbs are strictly verbs that are combinations of a simple verb form with an adverbial particle (forming a unit).

You didn't even mention"get somebody to do something. That was the question. [They put your comment in the other section on the French site. (sigh)]

@Lambie That was part of the question, and I believe there is nothing idiomatic about this one. You might do that part yourself as a partial answer. // This shows that they (whoever they are) are permanently on our back spying on our every word and thought.
